# Bug in lib support V7 with startSupportActionMode

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

In a ActionBarActivity (lib support V7), when i call startSupportActionMode() from my nexus 4 (4.3), in callback, i have a double call to onPrepareActionMode() because the onDestroyActionMode is also called.

In other terms, the bug is:

1 > startSupportActionMode(callback);
2 > callback.onPrepareActionMode() is triggered
3 > callback.onDestroyActionMode() is triggered (not by me, not normal)
4 > callback.onPrepareActionMode() is triggered

The good result must be:
1 > startSupportActionMode(callback);
2 > callback.onPrepareActionMode() is triggered
and only if i call actionmode.finish(), callback.onDestroyActionMode() is triggered

if I use startActionMode() (native api version), no problem...

i've create an issue on b.android.com and there is an exemple project.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a known issue and will be fixed in the next release of AppCompat

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58321