# ActionBar contextual menu

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to enter the Contextual ActionBar when the user clicks on an item in the listview. I have this code.

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback(){

        @Override 
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
              MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_action_bar, menu);
              return true;
            }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item1:
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_item2:
                    //close the action mode
                    //mode.finish();
                    return true;
                default:
                    mode.finish();
                    return false;
           }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    };
```

In the same class I have

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            { 

                startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);                
            }

    });
```

The problem is that Eclipse give me an error in startActionMode:

> The method startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (ActionMode.Callback)

How can I solve this?

Comment: which Android version are you testing with?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using the support library, you must use `startSupportActionMode(Callback)` instead of  `startActionMode(Callback)` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/view/ActionMode.Callback.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your code,check these imports

```
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
```

and try to clean and build again.

Comment: I've this import except the ActionMode because i'm using v7 support library, so i import import android.support.v7.view.ActionMode;
Is this the error?

Comment: See this may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632206/bug-in-lib-support-v7-with-startsupportactionmode